# How can I fix the issue: "Cannot resolve method 'getById' in 'EmployeeRepository'"?

Tags: java, spring

I've already checked similar questions, but none of them wasn't helpful for me:

1. [Cannot resolve method, spring boot app using JPA Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60393421/8370915)
2. [Cannot resolve symbol repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74087915/8370915)
3. [Spring crudrepository method save - cannot resolve method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012093/8370915)

I have the following code in service implementation with *business-logic* for the project as:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public MessageResponse createEmployee(EmployeeRequest employeeRequest) {
        Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
        newEmployee.setFirstName(employeeRequest.getFirstName());
        newEmployee.setLastname(employeeRequest.getLastname());
        newEmployee.setPhoneNumber(employeeRequest.getPhoneNumber());
        newEmployee.setEmail(employeeRequest.getEmail());
        newEmployee.setSalary(employeeRequest.getSalary());
        newEmployee.setDepartment(employeeRequest.getDepartment());
        employeeRepository.save(newEmployee);
        return new MessageResponse("New Employee created successfully");

    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Employee> updateEmployee(Integer employeeId, EmployeeRequest employeeRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId);
        if (employee.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee", "id", employeeId);
        } else {
            employee.get().setFirstName(employeeRequest.getFirstName());
            employee.get().setLastname(employeeRequest.getLastname());
            employee.get().setPhoneNumber(employeeRequest.getPhoneNumber());
            employee.get().setEmail(employeeRequest.getEmail());
            employee.get().setSalary(employeeRequest.getSalary());
            employee.get().setDepartment(employeeRequest.getDepartment());
            employeeRepository.save(employee.get());
            return employee;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getASingleEmployee(Integer employeeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        return employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee", "id", employeeId));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        if (employeeRepository.getById(employeeId).getId().equals(employeeId)) {
            employeeRepository.deleteById(employeeId);
        } else throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee", "id", employeeId);
    }
}
```

The *APIs* controller with the code as:

```
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployee();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.getASingleEmployee(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> addEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeRequest employee) {
        MessageResponse newEmployee = employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newEmployee, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public Optional<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody EmployeeRequest employee) {
        return employeeService.updateEmployee(id, employee);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

In `POM` I had:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

While working with the project, I've reproduced the issue as:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getById' in 'EmployeeRepository'
```

[image]

After some investigations, I've found the cause and the way how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of issue was the version of the dependency as:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

To fix it, I needed to change *the version* to higher, for example, to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

or to another one as:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

but for the usage of `2.7.5` version, you need to be *careful* and *aware*, because:

> `getById(ID)` is deprecated and you should use instead
> [getReferenceById(ID)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html).

Comment: `#getReferenceById(ID)` method is unreliable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74824683/3426309